# Is there a way to tell if the Android MediaPlayer is currently playing a song?

Tags: android

I have looked into the MediaPlayer documentation for Android, but this seems to be primarily for playing media in a localized media player.  I just want to be able to tell if music is playing in Android default Media Player.

Thanks

Comment: sorry - couldn't resist: Ears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioManager::isMusicActive() Checks whether any music is active.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Answer (score 1):

See if that helps you: http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/